# Validate System.DateTime is in a UTC format

Tags: c#, timezone, nodatime

I have a requirement to store all of the dates recorded in database must be recorded as UTC. So far I can achieve this using Noda library with following method:

```
    public static DateTime NowUtc(string timeZoneId)
    {
        var timeZone = GetTimeZone(timeZoneId);
        var instant = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
        return instant.InZone(timeZone).ToDateTimeUtc();
    }
```

I'm going to validate every date that passed into data access layer must be in UTC format.

How do I achieve that?

Thanks

Note: I have created a custom class library that used Noda as the core engine and the output is converted back to System.DateTime.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking, but here are some tips:

- If all you need is "now" as a UTC `DateTime`, just use `DateTime.UtcNow`.
- If you are working with Noda Time instants and need a `DateTime`, just use `instant.ToDateTimeUtc()`.  There's no point in working with time zones if you just need UTC.
- If you want to validate a `DateTime` is in UTC, then check the kind:

  ```
  dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc
  ```
- Your data layer will probably return `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` kinds of `DateTime`, so you would need to first specify the UTC kind before converting to a Noda Time `Instant`:

  ```
  DateTime dt = (DateTime) dataReader["YourDataField"];
  DateTime utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc);
  Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utc);
  ```
- Lastly, recognize that UTC isn't a *format*.  It's a time scale.  So a value can be "adjusted to UTC", or "of UTC kind", but it can't be "in UTC format".

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but +1

Answer (score -1):

Please go through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx

```
DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;

DateTimeOffset utc = localServerTime.ToUniversalTime();

Console.WriteLine("UTC:{0}", utc);
```

Comment: Why go through the local time when you can just use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`?